# [gruntjs]How to update ES6 import statements in uglify section of Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify, gruntfile

module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({

```
uglify: {
            'minify-each':{ 
                options : {
                    beautify: false, 
                    mangle: false,  
                    sourceMap: true,
                    compress: {
                        drop_console: true 
                    }
                },
                files: [{
                    cwd: 'src/private/assets/js/',
                    src: '**/*.js',
                    dest: 'src/public/assets/js/',
                    expand: true,
                    flatten: false,
                    ext: '.min.js' //Extension not used in ES6 import statements
                }]
            }
```

});

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.registerTask('run', ['uglify']);
```

};

### In each *.js file, there are ES6 import statements, for example:

in file1.js, I have...

import { getConstants, getUtils } from '../assets/js/utils.js';
import { WidgetClass } from '../assets/js/classes.js';

### class ProcessMain {}

The issue is when performing minification on file1.js in Gruntfile.js, those import statements are maintained, but do want to be able to replace each import statement as follows:

import { getConstants, getUtils } from '../assets/js/utils.min.js';
import { WidgetClass } from '../assets/js/classes.min.js';

Are there ways to capture each line in file1.js to update the import statements?

Within uglify object in Gruntfile.js, I have replaced:

ext: '.min.js' //Extension not used in ES6 import statements
--with--
ext: '.js' //Extension used in ES6 import statements

and that seems to do the trick, perhaps, resolves the issue. However, it is not standard since the minified file1.js does not have a *.min.js extension.